# Hibernate delete all objects associations that reference the object unidirectional using ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `ModuleData` object and a `Setting` object that references this `ModuleData` object, but the `ModuleData` object does not have any reference to the `Setting` object. Does Hibernate automatically delete the objects that reference `ModuleData` and if not, how do I accomplish that Hibernate does this.

ModuleData.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "modules")
public class ModuleData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private String version;
}
```

Setting.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"settingKey"}))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Setting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "settingKey", nullable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "moduleId", nullable = false)
    private ModuleData module;
```

I will delete by `session.delete(moduleData)`.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this using by using cascade types?

Comment: I used Hibernate's `@OnDelete(OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` to do this. Added it to the module variable of Setting.

Comment: Ah ok great, glad to know that the 'cascade' was the right ballpark.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the other side of the relation (i.e. add the Setting property to the ModuleData class), and then use Java Persistence 'cascade types' to accomplish this. Specifically the CascadeType.REMOVE will give you the desired behavior. From [this great tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), your ModuleData class would reference its Setting child similar to this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

so it would look something like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, ...)
private List<Setting> settings;
```

Another great tutorial on cascade types:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types